# Multiple CC emails says email does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel

I create a simple CC script that will attach from database to Mail::send. However, previous code was successfully submitting and working, until later this weekend, it went back to this message along with the Laravel error.

> Swift_RfcComplianceException
>
> Address in mailbox given [email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com]
>   does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

This is the code where I pull out the email(s) from database. This will depend if all the properties have emails.

```
if( !empty($contact) ) {
  $property_contact = implode(',', array_filter(array_unique($contact)));
}

// Output when using dd($property_contact);
// “email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com”
```

Here’s the script for `Mail::send`

```
//send email to owner                
Mail::send('_dash.emails.profile', $contacts, function ($message) use ($property_contact) {                             
  $ownerEmail = "myemail@info.com";
  $ownerName = "Information";
  $recipient_name  = Request::get('firstname') .' '. Request::get('lastname');
  $recipient_email = explode(';', Input::get('email')); // Need to explode the array if value are more than one

  print_r($property_contact);

  $message->from($recipient_email[0],$recipient_name);
  $message->to($ownerEmail,$ownerName)->cc($property_contact);
  $message->subject("Profile Update");                 
});
```

**Explanation:**

This is for the user when they updated their profile it will update/notify the admin about their new info along with the other property managers ($property_contact). These property managers will be added as CC and numbers of property managers will depend how many property this user connected.

If the user have 9 properties connection, whenever he update his profile, these 9 property managers will receive the update information.

**Case Issue:**

Base on Laravel error info, it does not comply the email format that passing from my script. *I believe I do not understand the standard format that this Laravel is looking for from my script to pass the value.* If I pass 1 value, it is working fine. But, whenever I add more emails, it ended up to this error.

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cc()` method accepts either one email or several email addresses in array.
So just edit Your `$property_contact` variable and You are good to go:

```
$property_contact = array_filter(array_unique($contact));
```

Code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Mail/Message.php#L132. Every method like `to()`, `cc()` `bcc()`, `replyTo()` using same method.

Comment: this make sense now to me. thank you. you save my life!